# Asymptotics of Geometric Distribution Moments

Tags: probability-distributions, polylogarithm

It is known (e.g., see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution#Moments_and_cumulants)) that the $k$th moment of a Geometric distribution with success probability $p$ is
$$\mathbb{E}\left[X^k\right] = \sum_{j = 0}^\infty j^k \cdot p(1-p)^j = p \cdot\text{Li}_{-k}(1-p)$$
I'm wondering if for a fixed $p$, can we find nicer asymptotic bounds as $k \to \infty$ for this value, say, in terms of just elementary functions? If it helps, we may assume that $p$ is sufficiently far from both $0$ and $1$, e.g. $p = 1/e$.